# Magento 1.9.1.1 + php PHP 5.5.9 AH01797: client denied by server configuration

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

I run Magento 1.9.1.1 and updated PHP to version 5.5.9, everything is working except I can't any longer ($POST) change anything through the backend. When editing a product for example and hitting save, the page reloads and nothing gets updated.

Logs show: [Wed Dec 29 09:16:45.043156 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 9779] [client 52.12.12.223:40942] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/app/etc/local.xml

I can still manually update using PHPMyAdmin by logging in using the same credential as in the Magento config file.

This is how my local.xml looks like

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Fri, 15 May 2015 21:07:30 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[MY_KEY]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[DUSER]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[DBNAME]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[myadmin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the files are updated in Cpanel, but the error says, that you don't have the permission to access or change the file.

You are not allowed to access the files inside the app/etc over the webserver. This behavior is defined here: https://help.nexcess.net/magento/what-is-the-client-denied-by-server-configuration-appetclocalxml-er... (pls don't change this, since this would be a serious security issue)

If the IP address shown in the log is your site’s IP address, it represents the Magento installation performing a routine security check. Its presence in the error logs indicates that the local.xml file, which contains sensitive credentials, is inaccessible over the Web. Your Magento installation performs this check whenever you log into the administrative control panel of your site.